# Unable to install libimobiledevice 1.3.1 version

Tags: macos, homebrew, libimobiledevice

For my project [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice) version 1.3.1 is required.
I am trying install it with brew command:

```
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```

and I am getting an error with info:

```
No package 'libimobiledevice-glue-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables limd_glue_CFLAGS
and limd_glue_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I was trying to install [libimobiledevice-glue](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice-glue) directly from git but after that problem still occurs.

Can someone explain how to perform steps to install libimobiledevice-glue correct way that command

```
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```

can be performed without error because of missing glue lib?